# Image Is Not Loading From Path

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The image is not loading from the given path in asp.net
here, is the scenario. I have uploaded an image into the folder using asp.net and inserted it's path to SQL server database, but when I try to fetch the image from the path which I have in my asp application "The path is correct" but image failed to load. There are no errors.

**Here Is the Code for Uploading Data**

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile && TextArea1.Value != null)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string path = Server.MapPath("/admin/images/" +fileName);
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/admin/images/" + fileName));
        //Response.Write("<script>alert('" + path + "');</script>");
        string ta1 = TextArea1.Value;
        string sql = "UPDATE homep SET img = '" + path + "', description= '" + ta1.Replace("'", "''") + "' WHERE id = 1;";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Updation Success ..!');</script>");
        }
    }
```

**here is the code for fetching data**

```
 dr.Read();
   Response.Write("<img src='"+dr["img"].ToString()+"' class='img-responsive'/>");
   dr.Close();
```

[This Image shows final output as i am getting content but not getting image from path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upse3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You serve a physical path on the servers harddrive to the browser, which the browser of the client can't open. You should build an actionmethod that serves the image and provide the url to that actionmethod in the src="" from your image.

for example:

```
Response.Write("<img src='/Serveimage/?path="+dr["img"].ToString()+"' class='img-responsive'/>");
```

and then create the 'ServeImage' actionmethod:

```
public FileResult ServeImage(string path)
{
    var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    return File(bytes, "image/png");
}
```

Comment: Thank your for the solution , but i am using database for retrieving the path . so can i put the path in this method which i am getting from database

Comment: yes. in the src of your image you still specify the path like you did in your intial code. This path is passed as an url parameter (see ?path=) to the actionmethod i suggested. This method wil read the file from the harddrive and serve it to the browser.

Comment: Note that for security reasons you should make some changes to your code. For example the ServeImage method just blindly servers any file on you server which you request. Also it may not be a good idea to put the entire path in you html but rather an id to the image and let the ServeImage method retrieve the path from the database.

Answer (score 0):

use ~ like this:

```
Server.MapPath("~/admin/images/" +fileName)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution , i have already done that but still not working.

Comment: There was an error for physical path , i was giving physical path but virtual path is required Done that from the Answer posted above.

Comment: i just give the path , and removed Server.MapPath

Comment: no do not remove Server.MapPath(image path here)....... then your image must be in your project file folder